# Dynamic programming approach of Hermite interpolation

Tags: geometry, curves, interpolation, dynamic-programming, hermite-polynomials

Let's define the $k$-th degree Hermite interpolating spline as a curve which interpolates between points $P_0$ and $P_1$ and also between their derivatives $v_0^j$ and $v_1^j$ up to order $j=(k-1)/2$. The interpolation parameter is $t \in [0,1]$.

Goldman [presented](https://www.elsevier.com/books/pyramid-algorithms/goldman/978-1-55860-354-7) a dynamic programming "pyramid" approach for the evaluation of a wide range of curves as series of recursive linear interpolations. The book states that Neville's algorithm for Lagrange interpolation can be extended to Hermite interpolation. In this case steps involving vectors ($v_i^j$) instead of points ($P_i$) become translation instead of linear interpolation.

For example the cubic ($k=3$) case is:

$P_0^3(t) = t^3 (v_0 + v_1 + 2 P_1 - 2 P_2) - t^2 (2 v_0 + v_1 + 3 P_1 - 3 P_2) + t v_0 + P_1$

which can be evaluated as

[image: evaluation of cubic Hermite spline]

However it is not straightforward how to extend the algorithm to higher degree, like quintic (5th degree) and septic (7th degree) Hermite interpolating polynomials.

It would be great to extend it to the quintic ($k=5$) case:

$P_0^5 = -\frac{ 1 }{2} t ^ 5 (6 v_0 + 6 v_1 + v_0^2 - v_1^2 + 12 P_0 - 12 P_1) + \frac{ 1 }{2} t ^ 4 (16 v_0 + 14 v_1 + 3 v_0^2 - 2 v_1^2 + 30 P_0 - 30 P_1) - \frac{ 1 }{2} t ^ 3 (12 v_0 + 8 v_1 + 3 v_0^2 - v_1^2 + 20 P_0 - 20 P_1) + v_0 t + \frac{ v_0^2 t ^ 2 }{2}+P_0$

I tried to make a pyramid for quintic Hermite, without success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use the standard Newton divided difference algorithm?

Comment: @Ian The primary reason is numerical stability. Linear interpolation - if evaluated as $P(t) = (t-1) P_0 + t P_1$ or using fused multiply-add instructions - guarantees that $P(0) == P_0$ and $P(1) == P_1$ in the floating-point domain.

Comment: This is the same reason why Bezier splines are usually evaluated by De Casteljau's algorithm (which is also a pyramid algorithm) instead of the polynomial form.

Comment: Makes sense I suppose. But now assuming that you want this property to propagate to all the relevant derivatives, that implies a polynomial of the form $(t-1)^{j+1} p(t)+t^{j+1} q(t)$ where $p,q$ are of degree $k-(j+1)=j$. So there are $2(j+1)=k+1$ variables and the same number of equations, so the polynomials are unique in this form in any choice of bases for representing $p$ and $q$. Moreover your numerical stability at the endpoints is perfect, and the linear systems for $p$ and $q$ are completely decoupled from one another (by the use of these $(t-1)^{j+1}$ and $t^{j+1}$ prefactors).

Comment: So it seems to me that the whole problem boils down to a choice of a convenient basis for representation of $p,q$. The "Lagrange" counterpart would be $b_\ell$ such that $\left. \frac{d^i}{dx^i} t^{j+1} b_\ell(t) \right |_{t=0}=\delta_{i\ell}$ for $i=0,1,\dots,j$ and similar for $t=1$. Not sure how easy those are to construct, though.

Comment: The expression $t^j$ can underflow easily if $j$ is high. Anyway, what do you propose?

Comment: My point is that if you want the derivatives to also be preserved in the floating point domain, then this decomposition into $(t-1)^{j+1} p(t)+t^{j+1} q(t)$ form is required, so that only the first term contributes to the derivatives at $t=0$ and only the second term contributes to the derivatives at $t=1$. If you object to that by virtue of underflow concerns then I'd guess that this problem is probably just unstable in general for large $j$ (which wouldn't surprise me).

Comment: Anyway, my proposal is to first determine what these $b_\ell$ are and see if they have any structure that you can incorporate into a dynamic programming algorithm. (Note though that I had an error, it should be $(t-1)^{j+1}$ for $t=0$ and $t^{j+1}$ for $t=1$.)